# How to call TWS Beans from another Java EE server

Tags: workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

How to call TWS beans from another Java EE server like JBoss or even WAS Liberty Profile?

Answer (score 0):

I've no direct experience with JBoss or Liberty, but we have tried several times from Tomcat without success. Maybe it's possible with Liberty but as said I've never tried it.

This is one of the reason we are moving to REST APIs that makes interoperability much easier. REST APIs has been introduced on TWSd with 9.3 FP2, but are still not available on TWSz.

If you need them on TWSz, you can try to open an RFE to push this new feature.

If you don't have a product/release that natively support REST APIs, a possible pattern is to implement your own REST APIs based on J2EE APIs and deploy them as an additional WAR on the engine/connector WAS, and the call these REST APIs from your JBoss, Liberty.